# How to disable GestureListener?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a gesture listener. I use DoubleTap to toggle a ListBox Visibility on my page.
And Flick gesture to flick images.

```
 <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <toolkit:GestureListener   
      DoubleTap="GestureListener_DoubleTap"
        Flick="GestureListener_Flick"/>
  </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

I'am trying to disable the flick gesture when the ListBox is visible. 
Can anyone help here?

Thanks in advance!
G.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably do this with a custom behaviour but I'm not really up to speed on them. I would just do the following in code behind:

```
GestureListener listener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(myControl);
listener.Flick -= GestureListener_Flick;
```

Comment: @GregorJ Please mark the answer if you find it helpful and relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that you can disable GestureListeners through flicking this boolean off:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.95).aspx

Might be simpler in some scenarios, but it will of course disable likely all events tied to that object.

Answer (score 1):

See my question about [WP7 slider strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342825/wp7-slider-strange-behavior)

I use

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.None
```

to disable gesture. Remember to save previous `GestureType`