# WP7 slider strange behavior

Tags: windows-phone-7, slider, drag

I'm developing Windows Phone 7 app. I have slider control on several page. However, when I go to a certain page within my app, all my slider controls in every page behave strangely.

The symptom is that user can only drag the thumb on slider for very short range.

The certain page I mentioned has no problem with code and XAML. Why does it cause ALL sliders to  behave wrongly ?

Comment: Which slider control is this with?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Its the standard slider control in WP7. Don't know how one certain page can affect ALL other sliders in other pages

Comment: Same here. GestureListener subscribes to an event and never unsubscribes, so it doesn't get released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that using toolkit Gesture will cause Slider to behave strangely. So when start manipulating on Slider, you should disable Gesture listener, then enable it when stop manipulating on Slider.

```
<Slider Height="84" Name="fixedSlider" ManipulationStarted="disableGestures" ManipulationCompleted="restoreGestures" />


GestureType prevGestureType;
private void disableGestures(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e) 
{
    prevGestureType = TouchPanel.EnabledGestures;
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.None;
    fixedSlider.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}

private void restoreGestures(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = prevGestureType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Slider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class has property [SmallChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.smallchange%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and if you look on the slider template, you will see, that when user tap on slider - value changes only on the small change. If you want to avoid this, you need to create custom slider behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by "value changes only on the small change", I try setting SmallChange to different values but the symptom still exists

Comment: Slider inherits RangeBase. RangeBase has property SmallChange. In link, that i provided, was page with desctiption of this property. On this page there is this text: "A control that inherits from RangeBase determines how this property is used. For example, when the user clicks the track of a custom scrollbar control, the Value property would increase or decrease by the value of SmallChange. ". If you want, that value of slider was exactly in that place, where user tap, then you need to control this from code. Create custom behavior and subscribe on Tap event.